# How to check if a number if divisible by two different values?

Tags: java, division

I've only just started college, and one of the first things we're learning is Java. I'm currently learning about if statements. For one of my homework assignments, I need to write a program that asks for the user to input a year. Then, the program needs to determine whether that year is a leap year or not.

The question states that if the year is divisible by 4, it is a leap year. Also, if the year is divisible by 100, it should also be divisible by 400 in order to be a leap year.

This is what I've written so far:

```
        System.out.print("Type a year: ");
        int year = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        if (year % 4 == 0 || year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0) {
            System.out.print("The year is a leap year.");
        } else {
            System.out.print("The year is not a leap year.");
        }
```

I'm expecting the program to check if the year is divisible by 4, or if the year is divisible by both 100 and 400.

Right now, when I enter the year 1800, the output says the year is a leap year, but I'm expecting it to say it is not a leap year. I suspect this is because the if statement is true when one of the conditions is true, which is the case because 1800 is divisible by 4. However, I can't seem to find out the right way to do it. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That’s just not what that logical expression does—think about where the parentheses implied by precedence go.

Comment: The pseudocode for this would be: year is divisible by 400 OR (year is divisible by 4 and year is not divisible by 100).

Comment: The first expression you are hitting is year % 4 == 0, this is true for 1800, as 1800 is divisible by 4. So it falls through to the "leap year" message. It doesn't check the other part of the OR, unless year % 4 is false.

Comment: If a number is divisible by 400 it is also divisible by 100, so you can simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is asking "Is year a multiple of four *or* is it a multiple of 100 and also a multiple of 400?" The second half is entirely redundant because any multiple of both 100 and 400 was already a multiple of 4 in the first place (same with 400 and 100 also) and the result is clearly more inclusive than you intended.

Remember that a series of AND'd conditions will restrict the scenarios that match while ORs will broaden it. So start with finding multiples of four and then refine that a bit by adding in the secondary condition about multiples of 100.

```
year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0) /* right! */
```

Since `A(B+C)` is equivalent to `AB+AC` in Boolean logic you could also expand this and it might read more clearly to you:

```
(year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 4 == 0 year % 400 == 0) /* expanded */
```

The parentheses aren't really necessary but I left them for clarity.

Another perspective that might help you think about this is reversing the condition to find the years that *aren't* leap years. It's very similar in structure to the one you attempted so I think that studying it might give you some insight where your thought process went wrong:

```
year % != 0 || (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0) /* NON-leap years */
```

Finally, one last thing to point out is that it only takes either side of an OR to be true for the whole expression to be true. Looking back at your original logic, once the program has determined that `year % 4 == 0` is true the rest of it is extra work that doesn't need to be performed. The program will actually skip those steps and this concept is called *short-circuiting*.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to word the leap year criteria is this: if the year is divisible by 4 but not by 100, or it is divisible by 400, it is a leap year.

It's the "but not by 100" part that is not expressed in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Example 1 (your fixed code):

```
    System.out.print("Type a year: ");
    int year = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

    if (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0) || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0) {
        System.out.print("The year is a leap year.");
    } else {
        System.out.print("The year is not a leap year.");
    }
```

Example 2 (other if for better understand)

```
    System.out.print("Type a year: ");
    int year = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    boolean isLeap = false;
    if(year % 100 == 0){
        if(year % 400 == 0)
            isLeap = true;
    } else if (year % 4 == 0){
        isLeap = true;
    }
    System.out.print(isLeap ? "The year is a leap year." : "The year is not a leap year.");
```

Comment: You needn’t test for 100 twice (even in the combined version); 400 implies it.

Answer (score 0):

Since any number divisible by 400 or 100 would, obviously, be divisible by 4. We would need to add additional check to make sure the year is a leap year

```
class Scratch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 1800; i <= 2000; i++) {
      if (i % 4 == 0) {
        if ((i % 100 == 0 && i % 400 == 0) || (i % 100 != 0)) {
          System.out.println(i + ": A leap Year");
        } else {
          System.out.println(i + ": Not a leap year");
        }
      } else {
        System.out.println(i + ": Not a leap year");
      }
    }
  }
}
```